# Extract first character of each word from a text and capitalize it with a function and return method

Tags: function, text, return, capitalize

def initials(text):
     result=bla bla bla
return result

## main

text=input("Please enter your text")
initials(text)

Comment: def initials(text):
        words=text. Split()
        letters=[word[0] for word in words]
        capital=letters. Capitalize()
        result=('. '.join(capital))
return result

Comment: where is the false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the list of tasks we will do:

Split the sentence into a list of words - step 1
Get the first letter from each word in upper case - step 2
Join them in this format: {letter}**.** {another-letter} - step 3
Return the value and print it - step 4

I've marked each step in the code comments
So lets go:

```
my_word = "stack overflow" # < Change this to any word you'd like
def get_initials(input_word):
  result = input_word.split() # step - 1
  final_result = ""
  for word in result: # loop through our word list
    first_letter = word[0].upper() # step - 2 
    final_result += first_letter + '. ' # step - 3, join
    '''
    So basically get the first letter with word[0]
    and add it to the final_result variable using +=
    and also add an additional ". "(a dot with a space)
    each time, as per requirements
    '''

  return final_result # step - 4, return

print ( get_initials(my_word) ) # and finally step - 4, print
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for not being cleared. It's my first post.. Yes, I use python. the task is tο 



to construct a function, initials (text), which accepts text as input and returns the text with the original first letter of each of its words converted into capital. For example, if I have: "Hello world," it will become "H. W." with dot and a gap between them. Also, the function should return (return should be used, not print) the result for each sentence.

Comment: Ah. So each *word* in a sentence? For example "My name is john" Will become "M.N.I.J"?

Comment: Exactly!! That's why I supposed I should have split as a method as well.. Don't know though

Comment: @Vickycoding hope it is clear now. If this helped you, mark it as an accepted answer please :-)

Comment: Thank you really so much! Just a clarification: I run it and it shows: "name 'my_word' is not defined" in the line with the print

Comment: and how do I press "accepted answer"? Thank you once again

Comment: Whoops, sorry forgot to include the `my_word` variable in the answer. Sorry :'(. And you can press the green tick mark left of that answer to do so. In case anyone else has the same issue and stumbles here, it might help them :D